# table co-relations by php& mysqli (joining?)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Table1 has 3 columns like

```
id | user | place
1    A      England
2    B      USA
3    C      England

<?php
 $sql=("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE place='England'");
 $query1=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $query1num=mysqli_num_rows($query1);
 if($query1num !=0){
   while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1){
   $id=$row1['id'];
   }
 }

?>
 //using above query i got two id who's from England
```

How to get how many(count) of them has php(where uid='$id') & how many(count) of them has java(where uid='$id') from table 2

Table2 has 3 column like

(id, uid, field)
 and 3 entries are values are

(1, 1, php)

(2, 2, java)

(3, 3, php)

Please, I am seriously new(learning php and sql).

Comment: If i understood the question what you need is a join http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: you need only with table2?....is there any thing yo need to fetch from table1?

Comment: @Vamshi.goli, Brother, I have to fetch from table1. I have to pass $id from table 1.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you can try this:

```
select field, count(*)
   from table2 where id in (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE place like 'england') 
   group by field;
```

You can see the output here: [SQlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f283/3)

Comment: Brother, how to combile your query with the previous query for table1?

Comment: I have to pass $id got from table1,and If I pass it through while loop give me result count 1  1, and if do without while loop it gives me 1. but result should be 2 where field='php'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<?php
```

`$sql=("SELECT field, count(*) FROM table2 GROUP BY field");`
 `$query1=mysqli_query($con, $sql);`
`$query1num=mysqli_num_rows($query1);`
 `if($query1num > 0){`
   `while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1){`
   `echo $row1['field']." = ".$row1['count(*)'];`
   `}`
`}`

`?>`

Comment: How to pass $id got from table1?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this i hope it will works

```
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)
{
    $id[]=$row1['id'];
}
$count=array_count($id);
echo $count;
```